# Show the limit of a sequence of real numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ as a sequence of real numbers and let a be real number. Show that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)=a<=>\forall\epsilon\in ]0, 10^{-6}]∃N≥10^{-6}\forall n≥N: |a_n − a|<27\epsilon$$
Where n,N are natural numbers.

Im not sure if Ive understood it correctly. Here is what I have tried:

if $(a_n)$ tends towards a then $∃\epsilon=\frac{1}{n10^7}\forall n≥10^{-6}$

which means that

$|a_n − a|<\frac{1}{n10^7}\forall n≥10^{-6}$

which means

$|a_n − a|+a_n<a_n<a+\frac{1}{n10^7}$

Taking the limit we get

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(|a_n − a|+a_n)<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)<\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a+\frac{1}{n10^7})$

which equals $0+a_n<a_n<a+0$

So we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n)=a$

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more like : $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = a \iff \forall\varepsilon \in \ ]0,10^{-6}]\ \exists N \geq \fbox{$10^6$} \ \forall n\geq N : |a_n - a| < 27\varepsilon$ ?

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = a$ is :

$$\forall\varepsilon > 0\ \exists N\ \forall n\geq N : |a_n - a| < \varepsilon$$

is equivalent to

$$\forall\varepsilon > 0\ \exists N' > 10^6\ \forall n\geq N : |a_n - a| < \varepsilon$$

Because if it's true for a $N < 10^6$, it's also true $\forall N' > 10^6$

Like before, it's true $\forall\varepsilon > 0$ si it's always true for $0 < \varepsilon < 10^{-6}$, and still true for $27\varepsilon$.

So now we have :

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(a_n) = a \iff \forall\varepsilon\in\ (0,10^{-6}]\ \exists N' > 10^6\ \forall n\geq N : |a_n - a| < 27\varepsilon\ \square$$